# Sql query with Shell : Invalid option

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, sqlplus

So I'm trying to execute an SQL query (Oracle database) in my script shell.

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/bin/ksh
login='mylogin'
pss='mypassword'

CE=`sqlplus -s $login/$pss << END1
set pause off heading off feed off pagesize 0;
select * from table1;
END1`  
echo $CE
```

But I got this error :

> invalid username/password; logon denied SP2-0306: Invalid option.
>   Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM}]
>   [edition=value]] where  ::=
>   [/][@]  ::=
>   [][/][@] SP2-0306:
>   Invalid option. Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS
>   {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM}] [edition=value]] where  ::=
>   [/][@]  ::=
>   [][/][@] SP2-0157:
>   unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus

Any help ?
Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure you're providing the correct user/password? What happens if you run `sqlplus -s mylogin/mypassword` ?

Comment: What's unclear about "*invalid username/password;*"?

Comment: I tried to provide directly my user and password but I got the same error

Comment: my user/pwd are correct , I'm sure

Comment: Add the `-l` flag to the `sqlplus` call to make it stop after the first logon attempt, which would clean up the error you see to just show the relevant part. If you’re really sure the credentials are correct maybe you aren’t hitting the DB you expect; is ORACLE_SID or TWO_TASK set to what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

**Example 1** Script is test_echo.sh

```
  #!/bin/sh

    username=\"Scott\"
    password=\"@T!ger\"
    ezconnect=10.89.251.205:1521/esmd

    echo username:  $username
    echo password:  $password
    echo ezconnect  $ezconnect

 echo -e 'show user \n  select 1 from dual;\nexit;' |  sqlplus  $username/$password@$ezconnect

oracle@esmd:~> ./test_echo.sh
username: "Scott"
password: "@T!ger"
ezconnect 10.89.251.205:1521/esmd

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Mon Jan 29 11:02:52 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> USER is "Scott"
SQL>
         1
----------
         1

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
```

**Example 2**

```
#!/bin/sh

username=\"Scott\"
password=\"@T!ger\"
ezconnect=10.89.251.205:1521/esmd


echo username:  $username
echo password:  $password
echo ezconnect: $ezconnect

testoutput=$(sqlplus -s $username/$password@$ezconnect  << EOF
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
show user
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')||' Test passed' from dual
exit;
EOF
)

echo $testoutput

oracle@esmd:~> ./test_Upper_case.sh
username: "Scott"
password: "@T!ger"
ezconnect: 10.89.251.205:1521/esmd
USER is "Scott" 29-01-2018 11:55 Test passed
```

**Example 3**

```
#!/bin/sh

username=\"Scott\"
password=\"@T!ger\"


echo username:  $username
echo password:  $password

testoutput=$(sqlplus -s $username/$password  << EOF
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
show user
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')||' Test passed' from dual
exit;
EOF
)

echo $testoutput

oracle@esmd:~> ./test_Upper_case.sh
username: "Scott"
password: "@T!ger"
USER is "Scott" 01-02-2018 11:04 Test passed
```

Configure the config file sqlnet.ora for an easy connection.

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES,ezconnect)
```

Change the password `@T!ger` to the user `"Scott"`.

```
oracle@esmd:~>
oracle@esmd:~> sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Mon Jan 29 11:05:04 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> alter user "Scott" identified by "@T!ger";

User altered.
```

Comment: How can I get the 'ezconnect' ?